# Google AdWords заблокировал контент сайта

Tags: google-adwords

Пришло сообщение от Google: сайт заблокирован, так как на нём есть вредоносное ПО, и далее идёт список ссылок, в котором картинки сайта, шрифты, favicon и т.д. На вопрос, как же картинки являются вредоносным ПО, Google ничего не ответил. Ответил только следующее:

> Ссылки, указанные мною в предыдущем письме, были повторно отмечены
>   нашими специалистами как вредоносное ПО, поэтому, к сожалению, без
>   удаления данного контента, сайт не будет разблокирован.

Как это лечить? Если нужно, могу прикрепить список ссылок.

Comment: Интересно. Можете добавить почту отправителя?

Comment: Почта отправителя adwords-support@google.com

Comment: Это очень частая проблема, как мне кажется Гугла. Интересно, автор, ты смог её решить? Мы пробовали пережимать, пересохранять и т.п. - это не помогло.
Но это что относится к картинкам. А что насчет .css в котором есть две строки и те с описанием стилей без единой ссылки?

Comment: @theblackpost долго переписывался с гуглом в итоге они сказали что всё нормально и разблокировали

Comment: Такая же проблема, как в обсуждении выше. Поддержка гугла сообщила, что в фалах сайта есть вредоносный код... Чем только не проверял, исход один - все чисто. Пример: https://f5-studio.com/wp-content/themes/f5studio-blog/assets/images/logo.png , https://f5-studio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/portfolio-ajflowers.png , https://f5-studio.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/winery.png Борьба и переписка с поддержкой продолжается 2 неделю...

Comment: Как я понял, такие ошибки возникают на сайтах с cms битрикс, битрикс любит делать кэш приписки к картинкам, изза чего гугл считает, что это вредоносные файлы

Answer (score 1):

Конвертируй картинки сайта любым редактором картинок. Оно уберет лишний вредоносный код, если таковой имеется. Как минимум просто заменит картинки на идентичные, но записанные по-другому и гугл может уже не придратся к оным после конвертирования.

Шрифты заново найди и проверь с помощью сервиса https://www.virustotal.com

Как картинки могут в себе местить вирус?
почитай тут: http://lurkmore.to/Rarjpeg

Или по запросу в гугле "Rarjpeg". Там описывается нужная тебе теория.

Comment: ну а например в чем заключается вредоносность данной иконки? http://ozero-cctv.com/favicon.ico её гугл тоже обозначил как вредоносную

Comment: Картинки сжатые через битрикс он считает вредоносными

Comment: У меня нету обьяснения почему гугл говорит что эти картинки местят в себе вредоносный код. Вирустотал на фавиконе ничего не находит. Вряд ли работники гугла будут разбиратся в чем дело более детально. Можешь, конечно, попробовать с ними договорится и добится обьяснений ссылаясь на то, что ни один антивирус там проблем не видит -- но вряд ли получится. А можешь просто пережать чем-то другим и разместить там же. Выше я просто ответил на твой вопрос -- как картинки могут иметь в себе вирус)

Comment: Сейчас бы на лурк ссылки кидать